# From OS Build 19041 to 20145

Tags: operating-system, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to install wsl2 with GPU accelerator enabled, to do so os built version must 20145 or higher, but my windows built is 19041. how do I upgrade to 20145

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Participate in the Windows Insider Program and select Dev Channel (Fast Ring). After updating, you should be in the latest build now.

Comment: This is actually windows 11 if  i am not wrong. The latest insider build for win10 is 19044.1147 (21H2)  source : https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/

Comment: @AlexanderVocaet https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/06/17/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-20150/ This is a Win10 build, but only in dev channel.